# Padding text sequences for conv1D change the output of the convolution

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I found out that even if new tensorflow api (since 2.0) and Keras is practical because we do not need to perform padding every time (even with only one input) during inference performing padding change the results of conv1d layer which do not accept Masking layer. The results change even when using GlobalMaxPooling1D.

Here is a little code snippet to explain my point :

```
import tensorflow as tf
y = tf.random.normal((2, 7, 100))

# Conv1d and maxpooling
cnn = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32, 3, padding="same")
max_pool = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPool1D()

m_post = max_pool(cnn(tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(y, maxlen=10, dtype="float32",  value=tf.zeros(100), padding="post")))
m_pre = max_pool(cnn(tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(y, maxlen=10, dtype="float32",  value=tf.zeros(100), padding="pre")))
m = max_pool(cnn(y))

print(m - m_post)
print(m - m_pre)
print(m_post - m_pre)
```

The thing that is really weird is, the output does not change among differrent padding size...

```
m_post = max_pool(cnn(tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(y, maxlen=10, dtype="float32",  value=tf.zeros(100), padding="post")))
m_post_2 = max_pool(cnn(tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(y, maxlen=16, dtype="float32",  value=tf.zeros(100), padding="post")))
print(m_post - m_post_2)
```

When I am in production inference, The solution is to pad the same amount than I did in training, but it is not optimal because I have really different text lenght.

Can someone explain that behaviour ? Did I miss something here ?